# haskell i/o putstrln error when calling function

Tags: function, haskell, io, demo

I have created a film database and functions related to the database.

I am now creating a demo function where it gives results of particular functions carried out when the number is pressed in ghci. For example, when demo 2 is typed, it shows all the films in the database.

I have managed to create most the demo functions however, i am having problem with 3 of them and keep being displayed with errors. I have commented out the ones which do not work and need help understanding what the problem is.

I have included all the functions i have created with the demo function below.

```
import Data.List 
import Text.Printf
import Data.Ord
import Data.Char

type Rating = (String, Int)
type Title = String
type Director = String
type Year = Int
type Film = (Title, Director, Year,[Rating])

testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [("Blade Runner","Ridley Scott",1982,[("Amy",6), ("Bill",9), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",5), ("Megan",4)]),
                ("The Fly","David Cronenberg",1986,[("Megan",4), ("Fred",7), ("Chris",5), ("Ian",0), ("Amy",5)]),
                ("Psycho","Alfred Hitchcock",1960,[("Bill",4), ("Jo",4), ("Garry",8), ("Kevin",7), ("Olga",8), ("Liz",10), ("Ian",9)]),
                ("Body Of Lies","Ridley Scott",2008,[("Sam",3), ("Neal",7), ("Kevin",2), ("Chris",5), ("Olga",6)]),
                ("Avatar","James Cameron",2009,[("Olga",2), ("Wally",8), ("Megan",9), ("Tim",5), ("Zoe",8), ("Emma",3)]),
                ("Titanic","James Cameron",1997,[("Zoe",7), ("Amy",2), ("Emma",5), ("Heidi",3), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Olga",7), ("Tim",10)]),
                ("The Departed","Martin Scorsese",2006,[("Heidi",2), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Tim",2), ("Fred",5)]),
                ("Aliens","Ridley Scott",1986,[("Fred",8), ("Dave",6), ("Amy",10), ("Bill",7), ("Wally",2), ("Zoe",5)]),
                ("Prometheus","Ridley Scott",2012,[("Garry",3), ("Chris",4), ("Emma",5), ("Bill",1), ("Dave",3)]),
                ("E.T. The Extra-Terrestrial","Steven Spielberg",1982,[("Ian",7), ("Amy",2), ("Emma",7), ("Sam",8), ("Wally",5), ("Zoe",6)]),
                ("The Birds","Alfred Hitchcock",1963,[("Garry",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Olga",4), ("Tim",7), ("Wally",3)]),
                ("Goodfellas","Martin Scorsese",1990,[("Emma",7), ("Sam",9), ("Wally",5), ("Dave",3)]),
                ("The Shawshank Redemption","Frank Darabont",1994,[("Jo",8), ("Sam",10), ("Zoe",3), ("Dave",7), ("Emma",3), ("Garry",10), ("Kevin",7)]),
                ("Gladiator","Ridley Scott",2000,[("Garry",7), ("Ian",4), ("Neal",6), ("Wally",3), ("Emma",4)]),
                ("The Green Mile","Frank Darabont",1999,[("Sam",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Dave",8), ("Wally",5), ("Jo",5)]),
                ("True Lies","James Cameron",1994,[("Dave",3), ("Kevin",4), ("Jo",0)]),
                ("Minority Report","Steven Spielberg",2002,[("Dave",5), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",2), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8)]),
                ("The Wolf of Wall Street","Martin Scorsese",2013,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",0), ("Sam",4)]),
                ("War Horse","Steven Spielberg",2011,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",3), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8), ("Zoe",8)]),
                ("Lincoln","Steven Spielberg",2012,[("Ian",3), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Liz",7), ("Megan",4)]),
                ("Vertigo","Alfred Hitchcock",1958,[("Bill",7), ("Emma",5), ("Zoe",9), ("Olga",6), ("Tim",10)]),
                ("The Terminal","Steven Spielberg",2004,[("Olga",3), ("Heidi",8), ("Bill",2), ("Sam",6), ("Garry",8)]),
                ("Jaws","Steven Spielberg",1975,[("Fred",3), ("Garry",0), ("Jo",3), ("Neal",9), ("Emma",7)]),
                ("Hugo","Martin Scorsese",2011,[("Sam",4), ("Wally",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Liz",7)])] 

------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------FUNCTIONAL CODE----------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------                

--when adding need to be addFilm string string int and the list name called testDatabase 
addFilm :: String -> String -> Int -> [Film] -> [Film]
addFilm title director year database = (title, director, year, [])  : database  

--Some functions needed later on:
averageFilmRating :: [(String,Int)] -> Float
averageFilmRating ratings
     = (fromIntegral(sum $ map snd ratings)) / (fromIntegral(length ratings))

--Formats the films for decimal, gives average rating of films instead of all users ratings.
formatFilmOutput :: Film -> String
formatFilmOutput (title, director, year, rating)
     = printf "%s by %s. Year: %d, Average Rating: %.1f" (title) (director) (year) (averageFilmRating rating)    

--Shows all films in the database    
displayAllFilm :: [String]
displayAllFilm = map formatFilmOutput testDatabase


--Shows films by director name
displayByDirector :: String -> [Film]
displayByDirector name
     =  filter(\(_,director,_,_) -> director == name) testDatabase

--Gives the average of directors films  
directorAverage :: String -> Float
directorAverage dir
     = averageFilmRating [rating | (title, director, year, ratings) <- displayByDirector dir, rating <- ratings]     

--These two functions give the films rated of average 6 or over  
filmsRated :: Int -> [Film]
filmsRated rating
         = filter(\(_,_,_,a) -> averageFilmRating a >= fromIntegral rating) testDatabase 

filmsaveragesix = filmsRated 6  

--Shows what films the user has rated.
userRatedFilms :: String -> [Film]
userRatedFilms username
     = filter ((username `elem`) . (\(_,_,_,xs) -> map fst xs)) testDatabase

-- Allows user to rate or re-rate film.
databaseNoFilm:: [Film] -> Title -> [Film]
databaseNoFilm database t = [(title, director, year, ratings) | (title, director, year, ratings) <- database, title /= t]
rateFilm :: [Film] -> Title -> Rating -> [Film]
rateFilm database findtitle (u, r) = databaseNoFilm database findtitle ++ [(title,director,year,(u, r):[(username,rtg) | (username,rtg) <- ratings, username /= u]) | (title, director, year, ratings) <- database, title == findtitle] 

--Displays films by year in descending order of rating
filmsByYear :: Int -> [Film]
filmsByYear year = sortFilms $ filter(\(_,_,yr,_) -> yr >= year) testDatabase

sortFilms :: [Film] -> [Film]
sortFilms = sortBy $ flip $ comparing averageFilmRating'
  where
    averageFilmRating' (_,_,_,rs) = averageFilmRating rs

------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------DEMO FUNCTION------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
demo :: Int -> IO ()
demo choice = do
    case choice of
        -- 1 -> do
            -- putStrLn addFilm "Gravity" "Alfonso Cuaron" 2013 testDatabase
        2 -> do
            putStrLn (unlines displayAllFilm)
        3 -> do
            putStrLn (unlines (map formatFilmOutput(displayByDirector "James Cameron")))
        4 -> do
            putStrLn (unlines (map formatFilmOutput(filmsaveragesix)))
            -- Get the director average of James Cameron
        -- 5 -> do
            -- putStrLn (directorAverage "James Cameron")
        6 -> do
            putStrLn (unlines (map formatFilmOutput(userRatedFilms "Zoe")))
        -- all films after Zoe rates "Jaws" 8   
        -- 7 -> do
            -- putStrLn rateFilm testDatabase "Jaws" ("Zoe", 8)
        -- 77 all films after Zoe rates "Vertigo" 3
        8 -> do
            putStrLn (unlines (map formatFilmOutput(filmsByYear 2009)))
```

The problem here relates to the demo functions which have been commented out. When uncommented and run the error for demo 1 relates to:

```
Couldn't match type `String -> String -> Int -> [Film] -> [Film]'
                  with `[Char]'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: String -> String -> Int -> [Film] -> [Film]
    In the first argument of `putStrLn', namely `addFilm'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      putStrLn addFilm "Gravity" "Alfonso Cuaron" 2013 testDatabase
    In the expression:
      do { putStrLn
             addFilm "Gravity" "Alfonso Cuaron" 2013 testDatabase }
```

It is a similar error for the rest of the commented demo functions

Comment: What errors do you see?  Also, that's a very large code example, can you show a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Comment: When uncommenting the case 1 i get the following error: Couldn't match expected type `[Char]
                                  -> [Char] -> Integer -> [Film] -> IO ()'
                with actual type `IO ()'
    The function `putStrLn' is applied to five arguments,
    but its type `String -> IO ()' has only one
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      putStrLn addFilm "Gravity" "Alfonso Cuaron" 2013 testDatabase
    In the expression:
      do { putStrLn
             addFilm "Gravity" "Alfonso Cuaron" 2013 testDatabase }

Comment: Try `putStrLn $ addFilm "Gravity" "Alfonso Cuaron" 2013 testDatabase`

Comment: @user3411002 try `print $ addFilm "Gravity" ...`

Comment: I second bheklilr's suggestion that you provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). Not only will that make it easier for us to help you, you may even figure out the problem for yourself.

Comment: @bheklilr same error again

Comment: @user3411002 Then you're using different code than what you've posted.  I just tested it and it compiles fine with the `$` between `print` and `addFilm`.

Comment: Thanks @bheklilr forgot to add testDatabase to the end

Comment: @user3411002 The error you get for case `7` is probably because `rateFilm` doesn't return a `String, but you're trying to use `putStrLn` on it as well.  It's the same issue, switch to `print` or convert the film database to a pretty-formatted string with `unlines . map formatFilmOutput`

Comment: Please could i get an explanation why the print $ makes a difference?

Comment: `print` is defined as `print x = putStrLn (show x)`.  It automatically converts its single argument to a string and then puts it on the screen.  The `$` is just a convenience operator, saying `f $ g x` is the same as `f (g x)`, and `f $ g $ h x` is the same as `f (g (h x))`.  It helps keep parens out of your code, which means that you have fewer mismatched parens.  You need it here because `print addFilm "Gravity" "Alfonso Cuaron" 2013 testDatabase` looks like you're passing 5 arguments to `print`, but it only takes 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you were having has to do with the line

```
putStrLn addFilm "Gravity" "Alfonso Cuaron" 2013 testDatabase
```

To the compiler, this looks like you're trying to apply 5 arguments to `putStrLn`, which is a function that only takes 1 argument, hence the compiler error.  If you were to do

```
putStrLn (addFilm "Gravity" "Alfonso Cuaron" 2013 testDatabase)
```

Or equivalently (and prettier)

```
putStrLn $ addFilm "Gravity" "Alfonso Cuaron" 2013 testDatabase
```

Then you're applying the 4 arguments to `addFilm`, then applying that result to `putStrLn`.  This still won't compile because `addFilm` returns a list of `Film`s, not a `String` which is what `putStrLn` expects.  You can instead use `print`, which is defined as

```
print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
print x = putStrLn $ show x
```

Or you could use your `formatFilmOutput` function:

```
putStrLn $ unlines $ map formatFilmOutput $ addFilm "Gravity" ...
```

and `unlines` converts the list of strings into a single string joined by new lines.

In case you're wondering what the `$` operator is, it's literally defined as

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
($) = id
infixr 0 $
```

The important part of the definition is the `infixr 0 $` line.  This means that it's right associative with a fixity of `0`, which is the lowest precedence.  Function application has a precedence of `9`, meaning it always takes priority over operators, so

```
add1 x * 2
```

Is *always* the same as

```
(add1 x) * 2
```

The `$` operator just acts as an alternative to parentheses.  You can use it as

```
f $ g $ h $ i $ j $ k $ l $ m x
-- f through m are functions of one argument
```

Which means apply `x` to `m`, then apply that to `l`, then to `k`, then to `j`, and so on, or you could write it as

```
f (g (h (i (j (k (l (m x)))))))
```

Which isn't fun to balance parentheses for.  This only works for applying the *last* argument to a function, not any of the middle ones.  So

```
add = (+)

add $ 1 + 2 $ 3 + 4
```

won't work, that parses as

```
add (1 + 2 (3 + 4))
add (3 (7))
add (3 7)
```

Which just doesn't make sense.